# How to update multiple ROS machines simultaneously?

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

So here's my problem...

I have 6 netbooks with Ubuntu 10.04 and ROS c-turtle. When I first installed everything I did so on the first netbook and cloned the image to the other 5.

Now I want to update ROS to diamondback, I could do the update one by one, but I'm guessing there is a faster way! What options do I have to update/install ROS and manage the robot's ROS stacks without having to work on the netbooks one by one?

Thanks for the help in advance,

Gonçalo Cabrita

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10141/how-to-update-multiple-ros-machines-simultaneously?/) by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 591 on 2011-06-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2011-06-01**:
has anyone created a puppet (http://www.puppetlabs.com/) recipe for ROS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can turn on all of your machines and have them connected to the network. Then you can use Cluster SSH to ssh into all of them at once from some master computer and update all of them at once. It will take the same amount of time required to update one machine, to update all of them.

If your 'master' computer is running Ubuntu, you can install cssh by running:

```
sudo apt-get install clusterssh
```

---

Originally posted by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) with karma: 674 on 2011-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2011-06-02**:
interesting package!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you know the commands that you ned to run to upgrade to diamondback, you could bundle them together in a shell script and then either copy and run on each machine individually or use SSH to execute the commands remotely.

How much time and effort you spend on setting this up now does depend on how often you expect to be doing this in future.  How elaborate is your ROS installation?

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2011-06-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2011-06-04**:
We are using Eee PCs with tiny HDs so space is scarce! Thanks for the tip nonetheless!

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2011-06-02**:
You don't need to uninstall the old install unless you need the space.  Simply updating the line "source /opt/ros/cturtle/setup.bash" to diamondback in .bashrc should be sufficient to force your system to use the newer release.  There are neat way to do this, but a straight file copy should work.

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2011-06-02**:
Right now I'm just interested in erasing c-turtle and installing diamondback plus a couple of extra stacks. Although it would be interesting to be able to simultaneously install stacks on all robots at the same time.